# Drop/add column containing primary key- SQL syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, syntax

I hate to post a syntax related question, but to be honest, I just haven't had much experience writing raw SQL statements. I apologize if this is a simple question. I have a table with a few hundred entries, and the creator of the table forgot to specify the ID column as the primary key and also forgot to set the identity constraint. So, I need to remove the old ID column and create a new ID column and set it as the primary key and as an identity column. I know I can use SSMS to modify the table manually, but I need to write a script that I can pass on to my client, as they already have this database in production, and this change needs to be made for several different tables. The script looks something like this:

```
    ALTER TABLE tblName
        DROP COLUMN Table_ID
        ADD Table_ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
```

When I execute the above query, I get the following message:

```
    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
    Incorrect syntax near 'Table_ID'.
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do was separate the drop and add operations into two ALTER TABLE operations

```
    ALTER TABLE tblName
        DROP COLUMN Table_ID

    ALTER TABLE tblName
        ADD Table_ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
```

Comment: This is nice but loses the values you already had in place for that field. This is not appropriate if you have child tables because you just totally blew up the data integrity. Be very careful with this approach. If you are sending it out to clients with production data, I would NOT recommend it. How was the value being set orginally?

Comment: In this case, I was normalizing a db that was horrifically designed. No constraints added for primary keys, foreign keys, or anything of the like. All of the tables referenced each other by a name field. At the time of asking this question, I would think the db was in an intermediary stage where the value of an ID column was insignificant. But your right... in a properly designed database, this statement could cause a lot of problems.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, I just wanted to warn anyone else reading this later, that there were potential problems with doing this.

Comment: Oh I know, I was just answering your question and felt like my original post needed a little more clarification. Like I said, you were totally right. This is NOT the right way to go about adding a primary key to an existing column.

Answer (score 1):

According to the syntax diagram, identity() is part of a [column definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). It appears to be available as an option only when you're creating a column.

That means this should work to create a *new* column with identity().

```
alter table tblName
add new_column_name integer not null identity(1, 1);
```

And this should make that new column a primary key.

```
alter table tblName
add constraint new_column_name_pk
primary key (new_column_name);
```

You might want to execute both those statements in a single transaction.  You might not.

I prefer to add new columns with all their constraints, populate them, and verify that everything went as anticipated before I drop columns.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that identity() can only be used for a column definition

Answer (score 0):

If id column is already an Identity, Just modify the table to make the id column the primary key

```
  ALTER TABLE TableName
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (Id)
```

if it's not, then also make that change to the column too.

```
   alter table TableName
   alter column id int not null Identity(1,1)
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but don't I need to set the "identity" property in order to enable auto incrementing?

Comment: Identity property??? You mean the Identity_Insert ?? Or do you mean make the column an Identity column?  If it's not already an Identity column, then you need to make it one. (see my edited answer.)  This is totally independent of whether there's a unique constraint or index on the column.

Comment: This gives me a syntax error: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Identity'`

Answer (score 0):

create identity field with primary key constant in your existing table:

```
alter table TableName 
add columnName int not null
primary key identity(1,1)
```